# When I created a repository on GitHub, it kept showing quick setup page. How should I remove that page and proceed?

Tags: java, github, repository, github-pages

When I created a repository on GitHub, it kept showing quick setup page, how should I remove that page and proceed?

Comment: Just push stuff to the repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick setup page only shows when there's nothing in your repository yet. What you need to do is follow the instructions and push something to your repository, then the setup page will disappear.

If for some reason the instructions aren't showing you how to do this, you have two options:

**Option 1: clone it based on the regular naming scheme**

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repository.git
```

Replace `username` and `repository` with your username and the repository name, respectively. If the repository is owned by an organization, replace `username` by the organization name.

**Option 2: create a repository locally and setup a remote**

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repository.git
touch README.md
git commit -a -m "Created README"
git push -u origin master
```

Again, replace `username` and `repository` with your username and the repository name, respectively. If the repository is owned by an organization, replace `username` by the organization name.

Comment: Before doing that, I have to clone the repository first. So how should I clone it, since there is no “clone or download” button under the repository name.

Comment: Well not really, you could also create an empty repository locally and push that. But generally, Github projects can be cloned by `git clone git@github.com:username/projectname.git` (or replace `username` by `organizationname` if you're in an organization)

Comment: Elaborated my answer with various options

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new repository you can check 'Initialize this repository with a README' and you will be taken to the normal github repository view.